# Cannot call methods on isotope prior to initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, plugins

The first time I load the page, loads OK but after you enter for example to the first project, then go back, it doesn't loads all the isotope items that are below (about 50 items) and it says "no more post" which is obviously not true.

I get this error: cannot call methods on isotope prior to initialization; attempted to call 'appended'

This is the [site](http://bit.ly/10cVtOp) I'm working on.

Any idea where is the problem? This is my code:

```
    function initBlog(){
        "use strict";

        if($j('.blog_holder.masonry').length){
            var width_blog = $j(this).closest('.container_inner').width();
            if($j('.blog_holder.masonry').closest(".column_inner").length) {
                width_blog = $j('.blog_holder.masonry').closest(".column_inner").width();
            }
            $j('.blog_holder.masonry').width(width_blog);
            var $container = $j('.blog_holder.masonry');
            var $cols = 3;

            if($container.width() < 420) {
                $cols = 1;
            } else if($container.width() <= 805) {
                $cols = 2;
            }

            $container.isotope({
                itemSelector: 'article',
                resizable: false,
                masonry: { columnWidth: $j('.blog_holder.masonry').width() / $cols }
            });
            $j('.filter').click(function(){
                var selector = $j(this).attr('data-filter');
                $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
                return false;
             });
            if( $container.hasClass('masonry_infinite_scroll')){
                $container.infinitescroll({
                    navSelector  : '.blog_infinite_scroll_button span', 
                    nextSelector : '.blog_infinite_scroll_button span a',
                    itemSelector : 'article',
                    loading: {
                        finishedMsg: finished_text,
                        msgText  : loading_text
                      }
                    },
                    // call Isotope as a callback
                    function( newElements ) {
                      $container.isotope( 'appended', $j( newElements ) );
                      fitVideo();
                      fitAudio();
                      initFlexSlider();
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $j('.blog_holder.masonry').isotope( 'layout');
                        },400);
                    }
                );
            }else if($container.hasClass('masonry_load_more')){


                var i = 1;
                $j('.blog_load_more_button a').on('click', function(e)  {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var load_more_holder = $j('.blog_load_more_button');
                    var load_more_loading = $j('.blog_load_more_button_loading');
                    load_more_holder.hide();
                    load_more_loading.show();

                    var link = $j(this).attr('href');
                    var $content = '.masonry_load_more';
                    var $anchor = '.blog_load_more_button a';
                    var $next_href = $j($anchor).attr('href');
                    $j.get(link+'', function(data){
                        var $new_content = $j($content, data).wrapInner('').html();
                        $next_href = $j($anchor, data).attr('href');
                        $container.append( $j( $new_content) ).isotope( 'reloadItems' ).isotope({ sortBy: 'original-order' });
                        fitVideo();
                        fitAudio();
                        initFlexSlider();
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $j('.blog_holder.masonry').isotope( 'layout');
                        },400);

                        load_more_holder.show();
                        load_more_loading.hide();

                        if($j('.blog_load_more_button span').attr('rel') > i) {
                            $j('.blog_load_more_button a').attr('href', $next_href); // Change the next URL
                        } else {
                            $j('.blog_load_more_button').remove();
                        }
                    });
                    i++;
                });

            }
            $j(window).resize(function(){
                if($container.width() < 420) {
                    $cols = 1;
                } else if($container.width() <= 785) {
                    $cols = 2;
                } else {
                    $cols = 3;
                }
            });

        $j('.blog_holder.masonry').animate({opacity: "1"}, 500);
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Can you give one scenario where exactly its occuring in the site?

Comment: Like I said on the question. If you open the link of the site, then click on the first project then go back to the initial page then the problem happens. Not all projects are loaded

Comment: I saw the error and it is located in `default.min.js > initBlog` function. I'm adding answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not working due to failure in `infinitescroll` in the site, it doesn't find `navSelector: '.blog_infinite_scroll_button span'` element

I saw that it is giving below error in your site, which comes from infinite-scroll plug-in.
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'debug' of undefined`

**[Recommendation from isotope specs for Adding Items](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/help.html#infinite_scroll_with_filtering_or_sorting) is, use `insert` instead of `appended`**

> **isotope - Infinite Scroll with filtering or sorting**

I recommend against using Infinite Scroll with filtering or sorting. This combination produces a unnecessarily complex user interaction that will frustrate your users. New content gets added, but part of it might be hidden. There is no way for the user to tell what gets hidden or re-arranged when Infinite Scroll adds more content. Exercise moderation with your Isotope implementation.

If you do plan on implementing Infinite Scroll with filtering or sorting (which is a bad idea), use the `insert` method instead of `appended.`

Comment: I examined from site and its failed due to infinitescroll failure.